# Redirect to the original requested page after login using AngularJs gives error Unknown provider: apiProvider <- api <- appAuth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I am developing a sample from to redirect page after login.

For this my conditions are - we want to do is that when the user tries to go to a page and he is not logged in, we want to redirect him back to that page after he login successfully

the idea behind the implementation is simple, what we will be doing is on the app load we will check if the user is logged in (there is a cookie), if not we will save the requested url* (the page that the user originally wanted to go to)* and after that we will redirect the user to the login screen when he login we will redirect him back to the url that he originally requested.

For this the Link I follow - [example](http://nadeemkhedr.com/redirect-to-the-original-requested-page-after-login-using-angularjs/)

My code is -

**Login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="app">

<head>

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

</head>

<body ng-app="myapp" data-ng-controller="LoginCtrl">


<div class="layout-app" ><!-- row-app -->


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">

            <div class="login">

                <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" style="border: 1px #ddd solid;">

                   <div class="panel-body" id="login-div">

                            <h3 align="center" style="font-family:Archer;">Data Archive Retention Tool <br/>(DART)</h3>

                            <p>&nbsp;</p>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                                    <div id="loginFailure" class="col-table-row" style="display: none">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-login">
                                            Login failed
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                                               placeholder="Enter email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                               id="password"
                                               placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click = "submit()">Login</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <span id='buildinfo' style="color: #ffffff;margin:0px;padding:0px;"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-lg-8">&nbsp;</div>
                           <div class="col-lg-4">

                               </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
`
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\\Workarea\\redirect\\login.js"></script>
<script src="C:\\Workarea\\redirect\\app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Login.js**

```
angular.module('myapp.LoginCtrl',[])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, api, appAuth) {
  $scope.model = {UserName: "", Password: ""};

  if (appAuth.isLoggedIn()) {
    $location.path('/');
  }

  $scope.submit = function () {
    var credentials = {
      "UserName": $scope.model.UserName,
      "Password": $scope.model.Password
    };
    api.login(credentials).then(function () {
      appAuth.redirectToAttemptedUrl();
    }, function () {
      $scope.ErrorMessage = "Login failed. Incorrect Username or Password";
    });
  };
});
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngCookies',"ngRoute","myapp.LoginCtrl"]);

//where we will store the attempted url
app.value('redirectToUrlAfterLogin', { url: '/' });

//this service will be responsible for authentication and also saving and redirecting to the attempt url when logging in

app.factory('appAuth', function ($location, $cookies, api, redirectToUrlAfterLogin) {
  return {
    login: function (credentials) {
      return api.login(credentials);
    },
    isLoggedIn: function() {
      return !!$cookies.FPSSO; //convert value to bool
    },
    saveAttemptUrl: function() {
      if($location.path().toLowerCase() != '/login') {
        redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url = $location.path();
      }
      else {
        redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url = '/';
      }
    },
    redirectToAttemptedUrl: function() {
      $location.path(redirectToUrlAfterLogin.url);
    }
  };
});

// When the app loads
app.run(function ($location, appAuth) {
  if (!appAuth.isLoggedIn()) {
    appAuth.saveAttemptUrl();
    $location.path('/login');
  }
});

//Setting up the interceptor to handle when the server returns 401
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('securityInterceptor');
})
.provider('securityInterceptor', function() {
  this.$get = function($location, $q, $injector, $cookies) {
    return function(promise) {
      var appAuth = $injector.get('appAuth');
      return promise.then(null, function(response) {
        if(response.status === 401) {
          delete $cookies.FPSSO;
          appAuth.saveAttemptUrl();
          $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
      });
    };
  };
});
```

In above sample it gives me [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=apiProvider%20%3C-%20api%20%3C-%20appAuth) - **Unknown provider: apiProvider <- api <- appAuth**

Comment: Where is your 'api'? I don't see any factory or service which named 'api'. The error is also pointing at that.

Comment: Thanks @HasanIbrahim I forgot it. After creating this it works.